# Prettier in VS code splitting attributes onto multiple lines ( print width doesn't work for html ) Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frameworks, prettier

I've searched a lot about it and tried so much solutions,

I'm using Angular when formatting html with prettier it's quite ugly because it wraps every single attribute to a new line e.g.:

```
   <button
      pButton
      class="btn"
      type="button"
      label="Add Item(s)"
      (click)="handleClick()"
    ></button>
```

- Print Width is 250 everywhere

[image]

- added `.prettierrc.json` file with `{"printWidth": 100}`
- Single Attribute Per Line isn't checked

[image]

Important thing to note is that prettier is applying printWidth 80 something like built-in because I'm sure that it's not set in any settings by user, I have some attributes that are two per line when they quite little in space e.g.:

```
 <div class="p-col-2" style="float: left">
     {{ "modules.user.orderdisplay.quantity" | translate }}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also check for .editorconfig file - if it is present prettier will use it's values.

Comment: Yep checked all the project for testing purposes I've deleted all `.editorconfig` files and reloaded VScode still the same issue

Comment: Ok, sot there is one more place. Open VSCode settings (you can user Ctrl+, or menu File -> Preferences -> Settings. In the settings search for "wrap" and you should find "Word Wrap Column", which would have a value of 80. You can try to change it.
The second setting you should search of is "singleAttributePerLine" and it should be unchecked.

Comment: word wrap was set to `off` and `Word Wrap Column` equals to 80 but anyway I changed `off` to `WordWrapColumn` and changed `80` to `250` and still not working

Comment: `singleAttributePerLine` I already posted a screenshot it's already unchecked

Comment: One more setting I have different than default. It is `HTML › Format: Wrap Attributes`, default is auto. I have it changed to `preserve-aligned`. Maybe this auto value is messing up.
And if that don't help then I need to check on clean VSCode install - I am sure we had the same problem and solved it somehow but cannot recall which setting it was

Comment: Yeah I already set it to `preserve-aligned` and not working cannot figure out if the problem is from my VScode settings or related to prettier the problem doesn't exist on other projects  same laptop nor my co-workers version of the same project that's why I deleted `.vscode` folder and still the same issue

Comment: Ok, that is new information. If it don't happen on other projects on your computer that means it is connected with this project or workspace. You say that it is not happening on your co-workers vscodes with the same problem. So that leads us to: problem with workspace configuration, with used version of prettier and with globally installed packages in npm. Let's try to investigate. Please disable all extensions in vscode, remove global prettier package, update vscode. If you are running Windows also turning off computer (not sleep / halt but full off) and turning on. Let's see if helped.

Comment: Actually I did removed globally installed prettier disabled all extensions and removed it from project dependencies as well ( deleted node_modules and package-lock.json ) did a fresh `npm install` removed the .vscode folder but the problem still exists quite weird really insane XD

Comment: Ok, very very strange situation. It must be a simple solution just need to find what. Anything related to editorconfig, prettier, used package will affect also your co-workers. Anything related to global npm packages or vscode itself possibly should also impact other projects on yours machine.
One of the last ideas - uninstall vscode, install it again. Then clone project from git into totally different directory, purge npm global cache, install packages and check. 
I am running out of ideas to do remotely - rest would be just me clicking and checking :(

Answer (score 1):

In settings.json put

"prettier.useEditorConfig": false

Comment: We already spoke about it in the previous answer, please read the comments